# Есть ли речевые ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите исправить!

*Гоголь показал всю жадность, продажность, дурность чиновничьей среды.*

Answer (score 2):

Гоголь показал всю жадность, продажность, недалекость чиновничьей среды.

Answer (score 1):

Нет слова *дурность.* Может быть, *непорядочность?* И потом, среда не может быть жадной, продажной. Может быть, заменить на *сословие?* Под ним, как мне кажется, могут подразумеваться сами люди, а под *средой* с трудом.

*Гоголь показал всю жадность, продажность, непорядочность чиновничьего сословия.*

Answer (score 1):

*Дурность* — в смысле дурость? Ну, в смысле — дураки они там все... Или в том смысле, что они плохие?

Я за *дурость*.

Comment: А вот не уверен, что у автора имелись в виду дураки. Они плутократы, а не совсем не дурость.